# calculate relative frequency by personId

Tags: python, dataframe, count, frequency

I've got data with columns: date, personId, label (True/False)

```
date         personId   label
-----------------------------
2022-07-20    1023      False
2022-07-30    1023      False
2022-08-05    1023      True
2022-09-11    1001      False
...
```

some rows may have zero True labels, some have zero False labels.
need to deal with NaN values, treat them as 0.

need to calculate relative_frequency=count(True)/count(True+False) by unique personId in a dataframe in python.

I tried groupby('personId'), but didn't completely get the way I want it. Looking for a simple, clean way to write this.

Answer (score 0):

This does it, using pandas `.groupby`, then post-processing those counts.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['2022-07-20', 1, False],
    ['2022-07-22', 2, False],
    ['2022-07-24', 1, True],
    ['2022-08-02', 2, False],
    ['2022-08-04', 1, False],
    ['2022-08-06', 2, True],
    ['2022-08-08', 1, False],
]

df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['date','personId','label'])
print(df)

df1 = df.groupby(['personId','label']).count()
data = {}
for row in df1.iterrows():
    person,label = row[0]
    if person not in data:
        data[person] = [0,0]
    data[person][label] = row[1]['date']

print()
for k,v in data.items():
    print( k, "freq:", v[1]/(v[0]+v[1]) )
```

Output:

```
         date  personId  label
0  2022-07-20         1  False
1  2022-07-22         2  False
2  2022-07-24         1   True
3  2022-08-02         2  False
4  2022-08-04         1  False
5  2022-08-06         2   True
6  2022-08-08         1  False

1 freq: 0.25
2 freq: 0.3333333333333333
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! :) I see... still has to use a loop... I was hoping not to use the loop. I even tried to create 2 separate dataframes, 1 for True count, 1 for False count, then merge, then replace the NaN values with 0s. But I didn't finish. Thank you.